# Setting columns for an empty pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is something that I'm confused about...

```
import pandas as pd

# this works fine
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'])

# but let's say I have this
df2 = pd.DataFrame([])

# this doesn't work!
df2.columns = ['A','B']
# ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 2 elements
```

Why doesn't this work? What can I do instead? Is the only way to do something like this?

```
if len(df2.index) == 0:
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'])
else:
    df2.columns = ['A','B']
```

There must be a more elegant way.

Thank you for your help!

## Update 4/19/2015

Someone asked why do this at all:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([])
```

The reason is that actually I'm doing something like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

... where data could be empty list of lists, but in most cases it is not. So yes, I could do:

```
if len(data) > 0:
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B'])
else:
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'])
```

... but this doesn't seem very DRY (and certainly not concise).

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in pandas. All of these work:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])
pd.DataFrame({}, columns=['A', 'B'])
pd.DataFrame(None, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

but not this:

```
pd.DataFrame([], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

Until it's fixed, I suggest something like this:

```
if len(data) == 0: data = None
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B'])
```

or:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data if len(data) > 0 else None, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Update: [as of Pandas version 0.16.1](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9939), passing `data = []` works:

```
In [85]: df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [86]: df
Out[86]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

so the best solution is to update your version of Pandas.

---

If `data` is an empty list of lists, then

```
data = [[]]
```

But then `len(data)` would equal 1, so `len(data) > 0` is not the right condition to check to see if `data` is an empty list of lists.

There are a number of values for `data` which could make

```
pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B'])
```

raise an Exception. An AssertionError or ValueError is raised if `data` equals `[]` (no data), `[[]]` (no columns), `[[0]]` (one column) or `[[0,1,2]]` (too many columns). So instead of trying to check for all of these I think it is safer and easier to use `try..except` here:

```
columns = ['A', 'B']
try:
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
except (AssertionError, ValueError):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

It would be nice if there is a DRY-er way to write this, but given that it's the
[caller's responsibility to check for this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L5029),  I don't see a better way.